# Finding a limit at negative infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}{x^2 + 2 \cdot x^7}$$

Hello,

I know that the answer to this is $- \infty$, but I'm having trouble showing it. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: HINT: $$x^2+2x^7=x^2(1+2x^5)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = -\frac{1}{t}$, now as
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}{x^2 + 2 \cdot x^7}$$ we can say,
as $x$ tends to $-\infty$, $t$ would tend to $0$. Note the negative sign.
Change the problem as:
$$\lim_{t \to 0}{\frac{1}{t^2} - \frac{2}{t^7}}$$
Solve to get:
$$\lim_{t \to 0}{\frac{t^5-2}{t^7}} = -\frac{2}{0} = -\infty$$
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it as follows:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}{x^2 + 2 \cdot x^7}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to -\infty}{x^7(\frac{1}{x^5} + 2)}$$
$$=-\infty(\frac{1}{-\infty} + 2)$$
$$=-\infty(0 + 2)$$
$$=-\infty$$

Comment: I disagree with your analysis.  From what you have written, $-\infty(\frac{1}{-\infty})$ could be an expression that goes to $+\infty.$

Comment: its usually not a good idea to bring $\infty$ while in the middle of problem involving limits

Comment: Sorry, that's what I've learned in my school, can you please explain what it's wrong to do that?

Comment: @user2661923 I think this cannot happen since $\frac{1}{-\infty}$ is going to zero and $\frac{1}{-\infty} + 2 > 0$ so why it could goes to $+\infty$

Comment: First of all, the comment of Albus Dumbledore prevails here.  That is, $\infty$ is **not** a number that can be manipulated but merely a symbol for positive or negative unbounded growth.  Your equation on its face is therefore invalid.  **Overlooking** that, your equation of $-\infty(\frac{1}{-\infty} + 2)$ becomes $\frac{-\infty}{-\infty} + 2(-\infty).$  Clearly the second term goes to $-\infty$, but the first term could (in general) **go to anywhere** : $+\infty, -\infty,$ or some finite number.  Consider for example the $\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^7}.$

Comment: can I use the limit law that says that the limit of f(x)*g(x) is the product of the limits of f(x) and g(x), where my f(x) is x^7 and g(x) is (1/x^5 + 2), and the show that the limit of f(x) is negative infinity and the limit of g(x) is 2?

Comment: @AniKhachatryan **Absolutely not**.  The limit law applies to (finite) numbers.  $\infty$ is **not a number**, but a **symbol** of unbounded growth.  Re my previous comment, compare $\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x^3}{x^7}$ with $\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x^7}{x^3}$

Answer (score 2):

As $x\to -\infty$ we have $$3x^7\le x^2+2x^7\le x^7$$ now squeeze....

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}(x^2 + 2 x^7)=-\infty$$
For any $M>0$ there exists an $N>0$ such that if $x<-N$ then $f(x)<-M$

That is $x^2 + 2 x^7<-M$.

For $x<0$ we have $2x^7<x^2+2x^7<-M$ therefore taking $N=\sqrt[7]{\frac{M}{2}}$ if $x<-N$ we have $f(x)<-M$