# Issues with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n*b_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) * \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

A few months ago I was answering a question of someone about limits.
And I use what I have been taught at my high school, the book that we learn from it says the following:

[image]

> Translation:
>
> limit = `نهاية`
>
> the product = `الجداء`

Specifically, I talk about the laws when one sequence at least diverges to infinity.
But one argues with me that this is actually wrong.

Now I am reading Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" and he approves that law is correct when the two sequences involved in the product converges

I see people say that a sequence converges to infinity but from what I read a sequence that goes to infinity diverges not converges, and Rudin didn't talk about this case (at least in the first three chapters).

So can we say that a sequence that goes to infinity converges and therefore the law applied, or the law apply for another reason, or there some wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that a sequence converges to infinity. When you say that a sequence $a_n$ converges to a limit $L$, it means that we make $a_n$ as close to $L$ as we like, provided that $n$ is sufficiently large. But we can't 'get as close to infinity as we like', since infinity is defined in a distinct way to the real numbers. More precisely, the neighbourhood of infinity is quite different to the neighbourhood of a real number. So it is very misleading to use the phrase 'converge to infinity'. Instead, you should say 'diverges to infinity'.

Comment: @Joe I understand this, but I see a lot of people with high repetition here say this, so I ask just to be sure, Thank you.

Comment: However, we *can* say that the limit is equal to infinity. Just keep in mind that saying that a limit is equal to infinity is quite different to saying that a limit is equal to $2$, or $3$. Roughly speaking, saying that the limit of a sequence is infinity just means that it gets 'arbitrarily large' and so does not converge. This is in constrast to when we say that the limit is equal to a finite number, where we get 'arbitrarily close' to the number being approached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, one says that a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of real numbers converges if it converges to a real number $l$. Then we say that the limit of the sequence is $l$, aand this is expressed by $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$.

However, this does *not* mean that this is the only case in which we can talk about the limit of the sequence. There are also the notions of the limit of a sequence being $\infty$ or $-\infty$, which is expressed by $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ and by $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty$ respectively. However, such a sequence does *not* converge.

And, yes, it is true that, for instance, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ and if $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=2$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_nb_n)=\infty$.

Comment: I know about the limit and when Rudin uses the notion $s_n\rightarrow+\infty$ he noted that we use it for certain typed of divergent as well as for convergent sequences but the definition is not changed, but since I saw a lot of people with high repetition use it I think that I miss understood something.

Comment: Since it is true is this argue correct or wrong?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926128/finding-a-limit-at-negative-infinity/3926136#comment8096810_3926136

Comment: @KaisHasan I agree with your answer.